Pop-up Generating Information listed
I am not the most techy person but have been messing around with google sheets and trying to automate a certain task at work. I am currently trying to create a button that would take the fields that has information listed and to have it automatically create notes. I know how to do this for simple sentences on google sheets but I wanted to create different buttons for different scenarios. I have recorded the macro and have the pop-up button listed but I am having issue of the formula coming through as the information on the pop up.
This is the script I have written on AppScript:
function NotActiveTest() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('123456');
  spreadsheet.getRange('B2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('name');
  spreadsheet.getRange('C2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('vin');
  spreadsheet.getRange('D2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('ford focus');
  spreadsheet.getRange('E2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('36 months 36 miles');
  spreadsheet.getRange('F2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('36 months 36k miles');
  spreadsheet.getRange('G2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('company');
  spreadsheet.getRange('H2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('123456789');
  spreadsheet.getRange('I2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('Agent Name');
  spreadsheet.getRange('M2').setValue;
  let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert = ("Company called " & G2 & " at " & H2 & " and verified with agent " & I2 & ", rep, that " & B2 & " the service contract is not active with a correct term of " & E2 & "");
}

I've submitted an image of what the notes look like before hand, and I'm just wanting the pop up to have the information on J2.

I tried to copy and paste the formula in google sheets into App Scripts but its just taking the text of it and not the actual formula. I am really new to this and have zero experience.

Try this:
function myFunk01() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sh.getRange("A2:I2").setValues([['123456', 'name', 'vin', 'ford focus', '36 months 36 miles', '36 months 36k miles', 'company', '123456789', 'Agent Name']]);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const [[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i]] = sh.getRange("A2:I2").getValues();
  ui.alert(`Company called ${g} at ${h} and verified with agent ${i}, rep, that ${b} the service contract is not active with a correct term of ${e}`)
}


I think you're asking how do you get it to generate a message from data that you type into A2:I2.  This is it.
function myFunk01() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const [[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i]] = sh.getRange("A2:I2").getValues();
  ui.alert(`Company called ${g} at ${h} and verified with agent ${i}, rep, that ${b} the service contract is not active with a correct term of ${e}`)
}


Hi! Thanks for your comment, I really appreciate it! The formula does work but when I put different notation in the google sheets, it still brings up that specific note. Is there anyway to make it generate a note what is listed in google sheets? Thanks so much :)

What do you mean when you say the "Formula" works? Please tell me how you are executing the function.

Sorry, I meant script. I have the script attached to the button that I press to generate the note

So I gather that you wish to enter the data and generate the note.  And now with the second version you can edit A2:I2 and the generate a new note.

That's perfect!! Thank you sooo much for your help, I really do appreciate it! Hope you have an awesome rest of your week Cooper! :)
